# Rails 4 : Customize Devise 3.1.0 for multiple role

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, customization

I'm having an issue using Devise. Well this is not really an issue but more a "I don't know how to do".

I'm actually using Devise 3.1.0 on my Rails 4 application. So far I only had my `sign up` through which users could go and register themselves into the system.

The problem is that now, I'm adding groups and roles to every user since each user gonna belong to a specific group (a company per se). So in that case, when a user first register, he register as admin and create his company. But let's say that from the inside of this application, this admin wants to create other users which all belongs to that sepcific company.

I know I could override the `Devise::RegistrationController` but looking at their original `update` method makes me feel that the code gonna be bloated if I copy their code and hack around mine in order to make it works.

My concern is especially about the `strong parameters`. Let me explain, actually I override the `account_update_params` on `Devise::RegistrationsController` as it :

```
protected
  def account_update_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:lastname, :firstname, :email, :current_password, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end
```

But if I want to add account from the application as admin, I need to also allow `:role` which can be a security issue in the register form. What if someone try to inject something into role while register?

How to do it the best way to allow `:role` only inside the application but not when logout?

Thanks to everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I too hate overwriting devise controllers. Part of the problem with devise is that it can be somewhat rigid and uncustomizable.

In your routes.rb file, create a new route.

```
get '/users/sign_up_as/:role' => 'devise/registrations/#new', :as => 'new_user_registration'
```

and then modify the devise registration view with the line

```
<%= f.hidden_field :role, :value => params[:role] %>
```

To make a link for sign up you could do

```
= link_to 'Sign Up', new_user_registration_path(:role => 'admin')
```

Also keep in mind that you are not required to use the devise registration controller for the form itself. If you run `User.create`, devise will still send the confirmation email, etc.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I didn't know that using `User.create` will still makes the authentication engine works. It fixed my problem to know that. Thanks :)

Comment: Cool, ya I have spent days of dev-time with devise trying to overcome issues like this. Devise is fantastic, but can be hard to customize.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I do it

Assumptions:
  1. When a user signs up, he is the admin for the new company
  2. Users can be created in app by admins or some other logic that you will apply

First, create an after_create for the User model in app/models/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create :set_account_and_admin

  protected
   def set_account_and_admin

   if self.account_id.nil?
     @account = Account.create!
     self.update(account_id: @account.id, admin: true)
   end
 end
```

Then override devise create in app/controllers/registrations_conroller.rb

```
def create
  build_resource(sign_up_params)

  if current_user
    resource.account_id = current_user.account_id
  end

  #...rest of devise stuff taken from the gem
end
```

Now when someone goes to your sign up app and puts in user/password they will get a new account and the User model will create a new account for you and setup that new user as an admin.

If that user logs in they can create new users then devise will see that the user is logged in and assign the new users to the current users account.

Now you can add whatever logic for admin/groups and who can create new users and not have to worry about adding the logic to the form.

Another alternative to this is to make a separate action in the controller like 'inappcreate' and route to that in the user _form.